Android Studio 2024.1.2 Palette/Attributes equivalent?
In earlier iterations of Android Studio,  you had a "Palette" where you could add elements like Buttons, Layouts, TextViews, and so on, and after that you had an Attributes box where you could define and update those elements. Is there a similar system in the more recent of Android Studio?
I've attached a picture of what I mean; I apologize for it being a little fuzzy. I recently updated to the most recent version, but I'm finding it difficult to use.

